# Where can I find an extensive list of the preferred chemical nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature, terminology

I'm writing text to speech software, and as it stands, I already have a method for reading out mathematical formulas accurately, which I have been using with chemicals as well. Thus, something like:

H<sub>2</sub>O would be read more or less as "Ayche, sub two, O".

and

CO<sub>2</sub> would be read more or less as "Sea, O, sub two"

That is fine here and there, However in a lot of texts this becomes extremely tedious, for example:

> In tissue, cellular respiration produces carbon dioxide as a waste product; as one of the primary roles of the cardiovascular system, most of this CO<sub>2</sub> is rapidly removed from the tissues by its hydration to bicarbonate ion. The bicarbonate ion present in the blood plasma is transported to the lungs, where it is dehydrated back into CO<sub>2</sub> and released during exhalation. These hydration and dehydration conversions of CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>

<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicarbonate_buffer_system</sup>

In this paragraph alone, you would hear: "Sea, O, sub two" three times. While I am not a chemist, I would assume that most listeners would prefer to hear would prefer to listen to a nomenclature that actually gave a name to the formula in cases like these, thus instead of hearing "Sea, O, sub two" and  "Ayche, sub two, O". -- you would hear the preferred chemical nomenclature,

- Carbon Dioxide

and

- Water

or

- Oxidane

or

- Dihydrogen monoxide

Is there a big table or list or resource available of the preferred nomenclature? And how often does this nomenclature depend on context, in the sense where the nomenclature would change depending on whether this was medicine or astronomy (etc...)?

Comment: Well, that would be a really big table unless you just made your own with a couple dozen or so compounds that are commonly used in English conversation.  However, it looks like you want it to apply to scientific texts, which certainly complicates things.  There are large molecules, for example proteins or even amino acids which would be horrible to hear anything other than their common names.  For smaller molecules, I'd just say "loose the sub". i.e. "sea oh sub two" sounds very odd but "sea oh two" is perfectly acceptable in most scientific contexts, as well as in everyday conversation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would your software differ from other text-to-speech software that already exists?

Comment: @halcyon Depends what you are speaking of. I use TTS engines, but I do not develop them myself. What I do specifically is I interpret wikipedia pages into SSML, and distribute the audio. Compared to a TTS application where you basically highlight text and play it back, I get rid speech artefacts, tables which are not good for speech, fix abbreviations, reinterpret wiki functions to optimize readable speech, control speed, parse the article into different consumable parts, add audible signals to inform the user of things like "Citation Needed", or for [] and () brackets surrounding text...

Comment: @halcyon And a lot more. I'm just starting to sell my audio now. http://frogcast.org/  If you want some free articles to demo, let me know. I'd love some free feedback in exchange, especially from someone like you who could intelligently remark on how chemistry articles are being read back, and what you think could use improving.

Comment: @Akiva, I'd love to test your software on some demo articles, and would be happy to provide feedback. I've used a few iOS apps in the past, but the speech artifacts were a bit distracting. Is it just wikipedia pages you've worked on, or can you do also do journal articles?

Comment: @halcyon Wikipedia articles are what I focus on, because of its relatively high and consistent standardization, and because its license allows me to sell as derivative works (All my audio is hence licensed as Creative Commons w/ Attribution). However, in query to the idea of other articles, this is something I want to branch out into. The more standardized, the more success I can have. In any case; people will enjoy best articles they are interested in. Name a topic or article and I'll send a bunch over.

Comment: @Akiva, here's a Wikipedia article or recent Science paper -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_ion_channel

http://science.sciencemag.org/content/355/6328/950.full

Comment: @halcyon Here you go: http://frogcast.org/shop/voltage-gated-ion-channel/ -- The price has been set to 0, so you can add to cart, checkout (No charge), and you will be given a download link. It is all creative commons, so feel free to do with it what you wish. Let me know if you want any longer articles or categories of articles.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Akiva, great! I'll get back to you within a week or two. How / where would you like feedback? I don't know if continuing this comment thread would be the best choice... ;)

Comment: @halcyon great. Reply here, and we can just delete our comments. Let me know if there are any other articles you want. Thanks again.

Comment: @Akiva, overall, I thought the reading was great. Better than the 1-2 I've used in the sense that it felt more natural and less jarring. More specific comments: (1) there's melodic noise that plays before reading the ion names - this is distracting.  (2) Cation is mispronounced as "cash-un" instead of "cat-eye-on". (3) Similarly, anion is mispronounced as "an-yun" instead of "an-eye-on". (4) in some places, a dash was read in as minus, such as with "S1-S4" which would be human-read as "S1 through S4."

Comment: If you want more test cases / comments, here are additional articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy_perturbation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennett_acceptance_ratio, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_integration 
(chosen to have some general science language such as the cation example).

Comment: @halcyon Ah those melodic noises would make sense in more regular articles. They represent ( and ), to help the reader know when something is being read in parentheses. Different noises also exist for [ and ]. I showed it to someone before, and they were able to figure out what it meant without me asking, however others have asked for a demo. Perhaps I can explain it at the beginning...

Comment: @halcyon And I will fix the Cation and Anion pronounciations. Stay tuned, I'll have those articles for you in a few minutes.

Comment: @halycon Ah, some latex! This will be fun!

Comment: @Akiva, I noticed that! They seem to be images in equations though, does your software handle that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55506/discussion-between-halcyon-and-akiva).

Comment: @halcyon Yeah, I spent a few months working on a latex to speech interpreter. Listening to it can be jarring because I ramped down the speed for visually impaired people to be given a chance to illustrate it in their mind while it is being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty extensive list on Wikipedia.

> **[Dictionary of chemical formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_chemical_formulas)**

I doubt this nomenclature would change much depending on context, given that there is a widely used nomenclature system (IUPAC) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_nomenclature)).